# What is a regular expression for this?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to detect if a string contains a string like the following.

> `ROCK="U3w9kE_ilAuWm3X1gFggmPBnyzE="`

`ROCK` + equal sign + double quotes + some non whitespace string which is at least 5 character long + double quotes.

I tried the regular expression

```
ROCK=\"[\\S]{5,}\"
```

When I try to match `ROCK="U3w9kE_ilAuWm3X1gFggmPBnyzE="` with this pattern, it does not match. `\S` is non-space character. `{5,}` matches 5 or more occurrences.

What am I missing?

The exact pattern syntax is

```
String pattern = "ROCK=\"[\\S]{5,}\"";
```

Comment: [It works for me](https://regexr.com/4fqvv)

Comment: `ROCK=\"\S{5,}\"` ?

Comment: Excluding quotes as in `ROCK=\"[^\\s\"]{5,}\"` would make sure that you're not over-capturing as against an input like `ROCK=".....", ROLL="....."`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your original expression is just fine:

```
^ROCK="\S{5,}"$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/2BC2y3/1/)

if we wish to detect that, this expression might likely work:

```
^(?=ROCK="\S{5,}").*$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/7JNGPr/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(?=ROCK=\"\\S{5,}\").*$";
final String string = "ROCK=\"U3w9kE_ilAuWm3X1gFggmPBnyzE=\"\n"
     + "ROCK=\"U3w45\"\n"
     + "ROCK=\"     \"\n"
     + "ROCK=\"\"\n"
     + "NOTROCK=\"U3w45\"\n"
     + "ROCK=\"U3w4\"";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### Capturing Group

```js
const regex = /^(?=ROCK="\S{5,}").*$/gm;
const str = `ROCK="U3w9kE_ilAuWm3X1gFggmPBnyzE="
ROCK="U3w45"
ROCK="     "
ROCK=""
NOTROCK="U3w45"
ROCK="U3w4"`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(match);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Emma, I think the OP's pattern works double escaping the `\\S` like `String pattern = "ROCK=\"\\S{5,}\"";`  In your pattern `^(?=ROCK=".{6,})ROCK=".*?"$` the anchors `^$` limit the string if it can also be in the middle as the OP wants to detect if a string contains a string. The lookahead asserts 6 or more chars after ROCK which do not take the closing `"` into account. This part`".*?"` can also match 5 spaces which I think the OP does not want to match.

Answer (score 2):

You should escape the backslash of `\S` like `"ROCK=\"[\\S]{5,}\""`.

Also you can try `".*ROCK=\"[^\\s\"]{5,}\".*"` using a negated group (not match) `[^...]`  with white space family and double quotes to not over capture as @Mike Samuel pointed out.

Here is a little class you can use for testing. Add test strings to the `tests` array.

```
public class Q56601920 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = ".*ROCK=\"[^\\s\"]{5,}\".*";

        String[] tests = { "ROCK=\"U3w9kE_ilAuWm3X1gFggmPBnyzE=\"",
                "xxxxxxxxROCK=\"U3w9kE_ilAuWm3X1gFggmPBnyzE=\"xxxxxxxx",
                "ROCK=\"U3w9kE_ilAuWm3X1gFggmPBnyzE=\",ROLL=\"U3w9kE_ilAuWm3X1gFggmPBnyzE=\"",
                "ROCK=\"U3w9kE ilAuWm3X1gFggmPBnyzE=\"",
                "ROCK=\"U3w9kE ilAuWm3X1gFggmPBnyzE=",
                "ROCK=\"U3w9\"" 
                };

        for (String stringToBeTested : tests) {
            if (stringToBeTested.matches(regex)) {
                System.out.println(stringToBeTested + " matches regexp");
            } else {
                System.out.println(stringToBeTested + " not matches regexp");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

happy coding

Comment: This test could be clearer if it showed the exact string being matched, because that would show over-capturing. How I did it was to import `java.util.regex`, then put the the matching regex (`ROCK=\"[\\s\"]{5,}\"`) into the `regex` variable and put the following two lines into the loop: `Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(t);` `System.out.format("%s | matches %s%n", t, m.find() ? m.group():"nothing");`

Answer (score 1):

In Java you need to escape a `\`. You are missing this in `\S`. Use this:

```
String regex = "ROCK=\"[\\S]{5,}\"";
boolean matches = "ROCK=\"U3w9kE_ilAuWm3X1gFggmPBnyzE=\"".matches(regex);
System.out.println(matches);
```

The result will be `true`.